# Referencing a Spark (Scala) library from a PySpark library

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I will be building a Python library for PySpark clients. This library will be calling a Spark (Scala) library that I already built and have in production. As motivation (and, perhaps, sanity-check), the Python library they will be calling would look something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.DataFrame import PyDataFrame

def process(python_data_frame):
    sc = python_data_frame.rdd.context
    sql_context = python_data_frame.sql_ctx    
    processed_scala_df = sc._jvm.com.mayonesa.ScalaClass.process(python_data_frame._jdf)

    return PyDataFrame(processed_scala_df, sql_context)
```

I would like to make importing/using this library as painless as possible to my PySpark customers. How would I reference my Scala project as a dependency to/within this Python library? I would like to avoid them having to add attributes (i.e., `--jars`) to the `spark-submit` command.

Answer (score 1):

`--jars` or `--packages` is the typical way to go with 3rd party libraries (like yours).

If you want to make their experience of using your libraries less painful, you might want to wrap `spark-submit` command with all the extra parameters into a wrapper script, which would definitely make it much easier to call.